# effective methods for user input in sudoku game

Tags: java

I am trying  a Sudoku game and  for this i have taken 9 buttons labelled  1 to 9 and 81 text fields for user input.i am trying to take input from that nine buttons.
   Now  how should  i code to choose a text field among 81 text fields so that user can input on any text field number 1 to 9 on mere button click.
      for example :Suppose i click 2nd button now how do i code so that user can choose any text field among 81 text fields  for placing 2.
one option is dragging the button on required text field .  But is there any other effective method to do this.
first approach working...

```
     for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
                    {
                    cellField[i][j].setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
                  cellField[i][j].addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
                      public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {

                          setFocused(evt);


                      }

                    private void setFocused(FocusEvent evt) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         selectedTextField=(JTextField) evt.getComponent();
                    }

                    });
                }
            }
        }

        public void updateString(String newValue) {
            selectedTextField.setText(newValue);
        }
    Action performed on one of the buttons..
    if (e.getSource() == b1)

            {
                String buttonText = b1.getLabel();
                updateString(buttonText);
            }

Transpareny code
private void createAndShowGUI() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.setLayout(null);
        setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("G://Wallpapers//ni.jpg")));

        pan1 = new JPanel();
        pan1.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 35));//transparency of outer panel
        // pan1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        this.getContentPane().add(pan1);
        pan1.setBounds(400, 100, 400, 400);

        // 3 rows and 3 columns
        // in the layout for the
        for (int b = 0; b < 9; b++) {
            cellPanel[b] = new JPanel();
            GridLayout cell = new GridLayout(3, 3, 2, 2);
            cellPanel[b].setLayout(cell);
            // pan1.setLayout(null);

            cellPanel[b].setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 2));//transparency of inner 9 panels
            pan1.add(cellPanel[b]);

            cellPanel[b].setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                    BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder(),
                    BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder()));

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                cellField[i][j] = new JTextField(1);
            }
        }//transparency of 81 text fields
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
                cellPanel[0].add(cellField[x][c]);
                cellField[x][c].setBackground(new Color(10, 175, 193, 25));
            }
        }
        // cellPanel 1
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            for (int c = 3; c < 6; c++) {
                cellField[x][c].setBackground(new Color(10, 175, 193, 25));
                cellPanel[1].add(cellField[x][c]);

            }
        }
        // cellPanel 2
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            for (int c = 6; c < 9; c++) {

                cellField[x][c].setBackground(new Color(10, 175, 193, 65)); // JTextField[3][3];
                cellPanel[2].add(cellField[x][c]);
                // cellField[x][c].setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,25));
            } // End inner for loop
        }
        // cellPanel 3
        for (int x = 3; x < 6; x++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) { // JTextField[][] cellField = new
                cellField[x][c].setBackground(new Color(10, 175, 193, 65));
                ; // JTextField[3][3];
                cellPanel[3].add(cellField[x][c]);
                // cellField[x][c].setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,25));

            } // End inner for loop
        }
        // cellPanel 4
        for (int x = 3; x < 6; x++) {
            for (int c = 3; c < 6; c++) { // JTextField[][] cellField = new
                cellField[x][c].setBackground(new Color(10, 175, 193, 65)); // JTextField[3][3];
                cellPanel[4].add(cellField[x][c]);
                // cellField[x][c].setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,25));
            } // End inner for loop

        } // cellPanel 5
        for (int x = 3; x < 6; x++) {
            for (int c = 6; c < 9; c++) {// JTextField[][] cellField = new
                                            // JTextField[3][3];
                cellField[x][c].setBackground(new Color(10, 175, 193, 65));
                cellPanel[5].add(cellField[x][c]);
                // cellField[x][c].setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,25));
            } // End inner for loop

        }
        // cellPanel 6
        for (int x = 6; x < 9; x++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {// JTextField[][] cellField = new
                cellField[x][c].setBackground(new Color(10, 175, 193, 65));
                cellPanel[6].add(cellField[x][c]); // JTextField[3][3];

                // cellField[x][c].setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,25));
            }
        }
        // cellzPanel 7
        for (int x = 6; x < 9; x++) {
            for (int c = 3; c < 6; c++) {// JTextField[][] cellField = new
                // cellField[x][c]).setNullRepresentation("");
                // JTextField[3][3];
                cellField[x][c].setBackground(new Color(10, 175, 193, 65));
                cellPanel[7].add(cellField[x][c]);

            } // End inner for loop
        }
        // cellPanel 8
        for (int x = 6; x < 9; x++) {
            for (int c = 6; c < 9; c++) {
                cellPanel[8].add(cellField[x][c]);
                cellField[x][c].setBackground(new Color(10, 175, 193, 65));

            } // End inner for loop
        }
        setSize(600, 400);
        setVisible(true);

    }
```

Comment: Why buttons? Use 81 text fields and the keyboard keys 1-9 to enter data and space to clear.

Comment: @laune just an additional way for user to input in case user keyboard is not working user can input through mouse.  user can input in either way

Comment: A text field is selected by clicking into it. Cursor keys can be used to select a neighbour.

Comment: I think I've also seen 9 very small buttons appearing in an empty field when the mouse is over it or the field is selected by a click.

Comment: @laune so is there any way out how i can use buttons to input text fields`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: @laune i was just asking if there is a way of using buttons 1 to 9 for inputting text fields.can you please tell how can i  make a local text field variable to hold the currently selected text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to have a global variable to hold either the text of the last clicked button or to hold the last selected text field.

First approach:
add a global text field variable:

```
private JTextFiled selectedTextField;
```

add this listener to your text fields creation

```
 textField.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
        public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
            setFocused(evt);
        }
    });
```

And in setfocused method:

```
private void setfocused(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                        
    selectedTextField=(JTextField) evt.getComponent();
}
```

And in your button event handler set the text in the selectedTextField to the number on the button.

```
private void updateField(String newValue) {                                        
    selectedTextField.setText(newValue);
}
```

Second approach:

add a global String variable:

```
private String currentValue;
```

add this listener to your text fields creation

```
 textField.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
        public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
            this.setText(currentValue);
        }
    });
```

And in your button event handler set the string to the number on the button.

```
private void updateString(String newValue) {                                        
    currentValue=newValue;
}
```

Comment: can you please explain how will i make a local text field to hold currently selected text field.

Comment: add this line to your class: private JTextFild selectedTextField=new JTextFild();

Comment: can i get the label of the button on button click and then set the same label on textfield when a textfield is clicked

Comment: Yes you can do that too.

Comment: thank you for the help  i am using your second approach while getting the label of button in the String newValue.but inspite of being set in the specific cell field the value is being set in all cell fields am i doing something wrong .please help

Comment: Can you edit your question with your current code so i can look at it?

Comment: i have got my answer from your first approach your first approach is working for me.thanks for that.but  i am getting two one on my textfield one which fills textfield and other small1 on the corner of the textfield  actual i have made my sudoku board transparent but the text fields are not getting transparent .also i am getting reflection of cursor on text field when i click on it.can my problem of two one's be due to transparency can you help me out with transparency code.

Comment: i am posting my code of transparency as well as working of first approach